# Remove extra slash (/) in codeigniter cron job

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have used this [Sitemap generate tutorial](http://www.wolfmoritz.com/php/dynamic-sitemap-codeigniter) to dynamically generate a sitemap for my CodeIgniter website. The Cron job code is `php-cli /home/username/public_html/index.php sitemap generate`. My problem is that the resulting URL has an extra slash after the site URL i.e `http://example.com//sitemap/generate` and this results to a 404 error. How do I remove the extra slash after the site URL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `$recipe->get_nice_url()` provide?

Comment: I think it is a custom function coz it is nowhere in the CI user guide

Comment: It is mentioned in library in link you provided. Are you using similar code in your application? Can you `var_dump()` it?

Comment: Are you saying the links in the sitemap.xml file have an extra slash after the domain? The `sitemap generate` command is not meant to be called from a browser (http), only from a command line.

Answer (score -1):

Check you config->config.php file for

```
$config['base_url']="http://localhost/root_folder/"
```

remove '/' here

```
$config['base_url']="http://localhost/root_folder"
```

or

Don't add slash in the

```
php-cli home/username/public_html/index.php sitemap generate
```

Comment: The first suggestion has not worked and for the second suggestion, the cron job will not work